# How to use psql with SSL key?

Tags: postgresql, ssl, private-key, psql

How to connect to a PostgreSQL server using psql with SSL key just like `ssh -i $KEY`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`PGSSLCERT` and `PGSSLKEY` environment variables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html) if you're not using the [default locations](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssl-tcp.html).

For example:

```
PGSSLMODE=verify-full PGSSLCERT=cert.pem PGSSLKEY=key.pem psql -h servername
```

Remember to use [`verify-full` for the sslmode](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-ssl.html), since the other ones won't protect you against MITM attacks.